# How to split multivalue parameter that is already contains comma in ssrs reports

Tags: ssrs-2008-r2

I have a SSRS report with a multivalue parameters `JobTitle`.
But `Jobtitle` itself contains ','.

So, how to split this multivalue parameter?

For example, I have records :

```
Responder,supervisor,Field distributor 1,worker,Field distributor
```

I want:

1. Responder
2. supervisor,Field distributor 1
3. worker,Field distributor

Comment: Two questions: first, #2 on your list has an embedded comma, so you don't want to split on commas.  What do you want to split on?  Second, what are you trying to do with the resulting strings?  Include them in a report's output?  Use as parameters in a SQL query?

Comment: I am using this parameter to generate a report, so when I select single parameter, report is fetched properly  , but when I select multivalues of this parameter report is blank because I have commas within the name, SO, I cannot split with comma

Comment: so is there any way, I can split this multivalue parameter

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you want to split at each comma. I used this expression `=Fields!JobTitle.Value.tostring().Replace(",",vbcrlf)`to get this

[image]

Comment: no responder is a single name and supervisor,Field distributor1 is a single name

Comment: What are the rules for splitting, in that case?  Is it every odd-numbered comma?

Comment: I am now taking id as value and displaying name as  text so now there is no problem in spliting the parameter